# Error creating new sites. The formula refers to a column that does not exist

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, site

I can successfully save a model of my site but when I try to create a new site with this model, I get this error:

*The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column*

I've searched and found that it's due to calculated columns, but even after removing my all 3 calculated columns, I save again the model and finally still have the error.

Can you tell me if I can do something else to resolve this issue?

I use some scripts using CSOM to modify values in some lists, can it be related to that?

Thanks,

Comment: Which error messages it gives?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Please check whether the brackets are removed in calculated column formula, if removed, re-add them or re-create the calculated column, then check result again,

Comment: Yeah I did it, and as I say in the question, I removed all my calculated columns and still get the error!

Answer (score 0):

Another place where formula can be added is under List/Library settings -> Validation Settings. Check if you are referring to any non-existing column.

Comment: where can I find these menus ?

Comment: Ok I've found the menu but don't have any formulas there